# Difference between "hypocrite" and "selfish"?

Tags: word-choice

How to choose between these two words? In which context should I use them? Do both have a negative connotation? I want to use them in a sentence:

> He is such a **selfish/hypocrite** person that he never thinks of other's pain.

Comment: A hypocrite (noun) is quite different from a selfish (adjective) person. Why are you confused, have you looked them up in a dictionary?

Comment: Yes i have and i did get their meaning. Its just the usage here(in this sentence) that i am asking about.

Comment: Then it depends on context. Does the "hypocrite" expect sympathy and comfort when he has a problem or is upset, but then appears cold and unfeeling when others are in similar situations? Or are you talking about someone who is self-centred and egoistic in general?

Comment: This is what the confusion is , the person being talked about is a bit self-centred as well as kind of selfish(you may say). So whats the exact word to use?

Comment: There should be no confusion, a hypocrite is someone who does the opposite of what he/she declares. For example if I say: "People should go to church every Sunday and read the Bible to their children" but if you never see me at church and I don't possess a Bible, you would rightly accuse me of being a hypocrite. (I hope my extreme example illustrates the meaning)

Comment: In your example sentence, it should be 'He is such a _hypocritical_ person.' Hypocrite is a noun, hypocritical is the adjective.

Comment: As an aside, there is no such thing as "for eg." That makes no sense *and* is punctuated incorrectly. It's either "for example", or "e.g." (with two periods), which already means "for example".

Comment: @RegDwigнt: Ok,your point taken. But it would have been better had you given an answer(to my question) along with the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two terms have both negative connotations, in your sentence I think *selfish*  may be more appropriate in the sense that you are referring to a person that don't care about other people's feelings.'

Or you may say  '*you are an hypocrite if you say that you care  about other people's feelings.*
You can be selfish, but not necessarily an hypocrite.

[Selfish](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/selfish): chiefly concerned with one's own interest, advantage, etc, esp to the total exclusion of the interests of others.

[Hypocrite](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hypocrite):
 a person who pretends to be what he is not.

Answer (score -1):

Being selfish is good. It is because of selfishness that humankind has arose to the top rung of Evolution. Being selfish means responding responsibly to your responsibility to take care of your own requirements to ensure your survival. To love your self.

You cannot profess that you love others more than you love yourself, unless you already love yourself. Otherwise that would be hypocritical.

Being selfish means being honest that you need to take care of your own self, your own clan, your own village, your own province, your own country, your own human race. It really depends on how wide the radius of your selfishness is. Being selfish is to visibly act to preserve what is important to oneself.

Being hypocritical is to either deny the need to protect one's own interest or deny you are actively protecting your own interests.

Even the Almighty Himself is selfish. He throws at us hurricanes, wars, diseases, conflicts, disasters, etc because he is actively filtering hypocrites out of the human race. Filtering out people who are not selfish enough to measure the width of the  radius of selfishness that would ensure their own optimal chance of survival.

He is filtering unselfish people out of the human race, and filtering people who do not realise that the preservation of our individual survival is at optimal when each of us consider the survival of the whole human race as our own self's. Not accepting that would be hypocritical. He wants to ensure there are no hypocrites for His eternal companionship.

BTW, G-d is not sending anyone to hell for not believing in Him, He assured me that. Whosoever say otherwise, are hypocrites. He prefers honest people, especially those who question Him.